# Fast Buttons for Mobile Web Applications

Tags: jquery, performance, click, mobile-application

I build a WepApp and I like to remove the 300ms delay on touch-devices with this code from Google

**DOC**
http://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

I not sure, I don't see any difference between both version on my HTC one X.

**Demo 1 (normal)**
http://jsbin.com/awejal/4/edit

**Demo 2 (with fastclick fix)**
http://jsbin.com/awejal/5/edit

I get (in Demo 2) additional an error in the console `TypeError: element is null`
but why? I don't get it.

Comment: In Demo 2 you call `getElementById("fastclick")` while there is no such element (and it results in "element is null" message). Most likely `getElementById("onclick")` or `getElementById("onclickJQ")` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is almost certainly from your typerror. A TypeError like that means you tried to call a method on a null object. You need to find out why you are getting that typerror, and then  fix it. Without the proper linking between the DOM and the jQuery the google supplied code won't help.

I think the line that is causing you problems is the

```
new FastButton(document.getElementById("fastclick"), goSomewhere);
```

because I didn't see any element with id `fastclick`.

Try fixing that and let me know how it works

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your method of detecting whether or not an element is toggled is correct? It looks like both `#onclick` and `#onclickJQ` share a common variable to detect which state they should be in: `bt = 0;`. As a result if you try to press one after the other, the second click event will have no visible changes. To solve this, use attributes to store data about the toggle state...

JS:

```
function blub(selector) {
    if ($(selector).attr("attr-bt") == "0") {
        $(selector).attr("attr-bt", "1");
        $(selector).css('background-color', '#aa0000');
    }
    else {
        $(selector).attr("attr-bt", "0");
        $(selector).css('background-color', '#333333');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#onclickJQ').attr("attr-bt", "0");
    $('#onclick').attr("attr-bt", "0");
});
```

Answering your question, to remove the delay, simply use [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and the [tap event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) that is provided with the library:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#onclickJQ').live("tap", function() {
        blub('#onclickJQ');
    });
});​
```

However, the first demo button [with the inline onclick event] must be modified to use the tap event specifically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#onclick').live("tap", function() {
        blub('#onclick');
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/jnY2n/4/show/

Tested on an iPhone 4S; the first div "lags" when it is tapped repeatedly, while the second runs smoothly.